# What network interface does Linux route traffic through by default?

Tags: linux, networking

I have a VPS with 4 IP addresses. I am changing the IP address of `eth0` on daily basis. `eht0:1` has its own IP address.

```
eth0 (192.168.1.3, 192.168.1.4, 192.168.1.5)
eth0:1 (192.168.2.1)
```

I have my custom written Python scripts those are continuously uploading data to remote database and other processes. I want to know which interface my scripts will use?

Because I am changing the `eth0` IP address daily, I want that my script will use only `eth0`. And I want to use `eth0:1` for ping and http apache server.

Answer (score 5):

It depends on your routing table configuration, not NIC interfaces.

So to find out which interface it is using, you need to know which gateway kernel uses to route the packets, e.g

```
%> ip route get 192.168.56.99
   192.168.56.20 dev vboxnet0  src 192.168.56.1 
       cache
```

Fom the output you can tell the interface in use is `vboxnet0`